# regextype with find command

Tags: regex, linux, find

I am trying to use the find command with `-regextype` but it could not able to work properly.

I am trying to find all `c` and `h` files send them to pipe and grep the name, `func_foo` inside those files. What am I missing?

```
$ find ./ -regextype sed -regex ".*\[c|h]" | xargs grep -n --color func_foo
```

Also in a similar aspect I tried the following command but it gives me an error like paths must precede expression:

```
$ find  ./  -type  f  "*.c"  |  xargs  grep  -n  --color  func_foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
find ./ -name "*.[c|h]" | xargs grep -n --color func_foo
```

and

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.c" | xargs grep -n --color func_foo
```

---

Regarding the valid paramters to `find`'s option `-regextype` this comes verbatim from `man find`:

> -regextype type
>
> Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex tests which occur later on 
>    the command line.  Currently-implemented types are emacs (this is the default),
>    posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended

There is no type `sed`.

Comment: "find -regextype help" gives an error that lists sed as a type... Specifically "find: Unknown regular expression type ‘help’; valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’."

Comment: @Ubuntourist The answer you replied to is nearly 8 years old, it's more than likely that changes have been implemented since then.

Comment: @Elhitch ~ You are incorrect mate.... that error still exists   

`find (GNU findutils 4.6.0.225-235f
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer contains some inaccuracies.
On my system, GNU find's manpage says to run `find -regextype help` to see the list of supported regex types.

```
# find -regextype help
find: Unknown regular expression type 'help'; valid types are 'findutils-default', 'awk', 'egrep', 'ed', 'emacs', 'gnu-awk', 'grep', 'posix-awk', 'posix-basic', 'posix-egrep', 'posix-extended', 'posix-minimal-basic', 'sed'.
```

E.g. `find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*\.(c|h)'` finds `.c` and `.h` files.
Your regexp syntax was wrong, you had square brackets instead of parentheses. With square brackets, it would be `[ch]`.

You can just use the default regexp type as well: `find . -regex '.*\.\(c\|h\)$'` also works. Notice that you have to escape `(`, `|`, `)` characters in this case (with `sed` regextype as well). You don't have to escape them when using `egrep`, `posix-egrep`, `posix-extended`.